# Taxonomy level parsing

Tags: java, string, parsing, brackets

I have following java code.

```
List<String> resultList = new ArrayList<String>();    
String taxonomyLevels = "(subject:\"Chemistry\" OR (course:\"Organic Chemistry\" OR course:\"Inorganic Chemistry\" OR (unit:\"unit1\")))";
```

Here, subject, course and unit are levels in taxonomy. Values in the double quote are the values of the each of the levels. I want the **combinations of all the taxonomy levels**.

I want this to be parsed and returned in the resultList. The returned list should have the following values,

```
"subject:\"Chemistry\""
"subject:\"Chemistry\"&course:\"Organic Chemistry\""
"subject:\"Chemistry\"&course:\"Inorganic Chemistry\""
"subject:\"Chemistry\"&course:\"Inorganic Chemistry\"&unit:\"unit1\""
```

**Update - Starts**

For the below input,

```
taxonomyLevels = "(subject:\"something1\" OR (course:\"somethingElse\" OR (unit:\"abcd test\" OR unit:\"efgh\") OR course:\"c2\" OR (unit:\"u2\")))";
```

the output list should be,

```
"subject:\"Chemistry\""
"subject:\"Chemistry\"&course:\"Organic Chemistry\""
"subject:\"Chemistry\"&course:\"Organic Chemistry\"&unit:\"unit2\""
"subject:\"Chemistry\"&course:\"Organic Chemistry\"&unit:\"unit3\""
"subject:\"Chemistry\"&course:\"Inorganic Chemistry\""
"subject:\"Chemistry\"&course:\"Inorganic Chemistry\"&unit:\"unit1\""
```

That is combinations of levels of the the taxonomy. In other words, combinations of subject, course and unit are needed.

It is kind of tree structure. Each Open bracket creates a new child level. **OR** between two same levels creates new siblings.

**Update - Ends**

I have tried several ways like taking one level at a time and getting next element and add with the existing string, but could not come with a solution.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have WAYYY too many quotation marks I don't know what you are trying to do with this String but you need to remove all the extra "" marks first and foremost or else you will get nothing but a ton of compiler erors                                                          String level = "(subject:\Chemistry\ OR (course:\Organic Chemistry\ OR course:\Inorganic Chemistry\ OR (unit:\unit1\)))";

Comment: @DavidColer. I have update the question. I need the double quotations, because if the subject has the values as **A OR B**, it might be confusing. And, there will be no compilation error as the double quotes are parsed properly.

Answer (score 0):

```
private ArrayList<String> resultList = new ArrayList<String>();    
private String taxonomyLevels = "(subject:\"Chemistry\" OR (course:\"Organic Chemistry\" OR course:\"Inorganic Chemistry\" OR (unit:\"unit1\")))";

public ArrayList<String> parse() {
    String[] temp = taxonomyLevels.split(" OR ");
    String[] clean = new String[temp.length];
    for(int i = 0; i<temp.length;i++){
        clean[i] = cleanUp(temp[i]);
    }
    resultList.add(clean[0]);
    resultList.add(clean[0]+"&"+clean[1]);
    resultList.add(clean[0]+"&"+clean[2]);
    resultList.add(clean[0]+"&"+clean[2]+"&"+clean[3]);
    return resultList;
}

private String cleanUp(String s){
    char[] chars = s.toCharArray();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(char c:chars){
        if(c!='(' && c!=')')sb.append(c);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

is this what you are trying to do?

Comment: I appreciate your try. But, it will not give combinations of levels. Please check my update in the question.